Delete record using class based view in django
How to delete record using class based view ?
I am using below view.
class UserDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'delete_user_confirm.html'

Is it possible to avoid template_name = 'delete_user_confirm.html' ?

If you need the delete view without the confirmation template, I wouldn't use the DeleteView class at all. I'd probably use a function view that returns a redirect to a success url:
def delete_user(request, id):
    # only allow POST requests (assuming requests are sent from browser not API call)
    if request.method != "POST":
        return Response(status=405)
    obj = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    obj.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("your_success_url"))

I think if you really wanted you could also override the DeleteView get method to call the DELETE logic but I don't really like the idea of a GET request actually performing the DELETE logic.
But if you do really want/need to do it that way it'd be this:
class UserDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)


Thanks @RHSmith. Actually I am using Class Based Views in my whole application. Why you wouldn't use the DeleteView class ? Is there any other alternative ? I am learing django.

Hi @abuabu, the class based views are definitely convenient and there's definitely a place for them but if you're not using templates for the delete view it just might be easier for the delete view to be a function. I find the class based views to be fantastic when working with templates though - they're really powerful for that!

Also just incase you're using django to build a REST API, I'd highly recommend looking into https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ and https://django-ninja.dev/ - they're both great frameworks you can use in your django project to build out REST APIs
